# GM Plateau observed in GM counter

Tags: experimental-physics, radiation

We had an experiment this semester using Geiger Muller counter, where we were supposed perform an experiment for determing the number of counts recorded by the counter for Cs-137 and plot it on a graph:

[image]

I would like to know why the graph comes out like this, with a plateau region, and then rises up suddenly? Also, if we keep on increasing the voltage then will we get another plateau or this rise will continue?

Comment: Hi and welcome to the Physics SE! Please note that you are expected to have thoroughly searched for an answer before asking your question - and to *show* that, by providing context to your question. Currently the question is unclear. You can consider checking the [advice on writing good questions](https://physics.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: The wikipedia page for GM tubes goes into some detail about this. Is there anything specific you're confused about?

Comment: Hi Ashwini. Hope you don't mind, but I've replaced your images of the data and hand-drawn chart with a single computer-generated chart (using [LibreOffice Calc](https://www.libreoffice.org/discover/calc/)) to make it easier to see the plateau and rise.

Comment: is the plateau actually a plateau? what do you get if you remove the last three measurements?

Answer (score -1):

First before a certain voltage  you count 0 events because the potential difference is too weak to accelerate ions and electrons resulting from ionization,  so recombination happens. After the plateau region where the rise of counts is limited, it means that counts do not rely on voltage value. It is where your counts are more credible, especially in the center of the plateau, which they call functioning point. Then after a certain voltage is saturation zone; your counts are just amplified by the big difference of potential; if you keep increasing it any more you will burn out the detector.

Comment: If you have a new question, please ask it by clicking the [Ask Question](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/ask) button. Include a link to this question if it helps provide context. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/239154)

Comment: @EmilioPisanty I've tried to edit out the spelling mistakes, and it seems OK now (incidentally, I put this one in the review queue with a flag a few hours ago). The terrible typing hid the fact that this does answer the question "Why do I get this shape?" The last sentence was a separate question; it probably meant "if you liked this, tell me what software you used". I've removed that.

Comment: FWIW, the software is [LibreOffice Calc](https://www.libreoffice.org/discover/calc/), as mentioned by Kyle Kanos in the comments under the question.